# {{#each}} not executing. Handlebars.compile(templateSource) not working properly

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Here is my advice.hbs file:

```js
<ul class="adviceParent">
    <li>Dummy text</li>
    {{#each slip}}
    <li>{{this.id}}: {{this.advice}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here is my app.js logic:

```js
const randomAdviceURL = `https://api.adviceslip.com/advice`;
const searchAdviceURL = `https://api.adviceslip.com/advice/search/`;

const htmlSelectors = {
    rndAdviceBtn: () => document.querySelector('header > button[name="adviceBtn"]'),
    searchBtn: () => document.querySelector('header > button[name="searchBtn"]'),
    searchInput: () => document.querySelector('header > input[type="search"]'),
    
    adviceParentUL: () => document.querySelector('.adviceParent'),
    adviceWrapper: () => document.querySelector('.adviceWrapper')
};
htmlSelectors['rndAdviceBtn']().addEventListener('click', getRandomAdvice);
// htmlSelectors['searchBtn']().addEventListener('click', searchForAdvice);

function getRandomAdvice(){

    Promise.all(
        [
            fetchURL(randomAdviceURL),
            getTemplate('./templates/advice.hbs')
        ]
    )
    .then(renderOnScreen)
    .catch(errorHandler);
}

function fetchURL(url){
    return fetch(url).then(jsonMiddleware);
}

function renderOnScreen([data, templateSource]){

    // console.log(templateSource); // FINE
    // console.log(data.slip); // FINE
    // console.log(Handlebars); // FINE

    let template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);
    console.log(template);

    const htmlResult = template(data.slip);

    // console.log(htmlResult);   

    htmlSelectors['adviceWrapper']().innerHTML = htmlResult;
}


function getTemplate(templateLocation){
    return fetch(templateLocation).then(response => response.text());
}
    
function errorHandler(error){
    console.dir(error);
}

function jsonMiddleware(response){
    return response.json();
}
```

Everything is working fine, but handlebars is not compiling correctly I think.

```
const template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource)
```

When I console.log(template) I get this:
ƒ e(a,b){return f||(f=d()),f.call(this,a,b)}

It's rendering the hardcoded stuff in advice.hbs but not the object I pass.

Comment: Handlebars is a well tested library and your `console.log` output of `template` is correct, since Handlebars compile the template to a callable js function. Try `const htmlResult = template(data);` instead of `const htmlResult = template(data.slip);`

Comment: Please update this `template(data.slip)` to `template({slip:data.slip})` or `template(data)` and try again

Comment: `htmlSelectors['adviceWrapper']().innerHTML = template({slip: data.slip});`
Now is rendering the li elements but not the actual values of properties of the object passed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was passing an Object and NOT an array of objects..
`htmlSelectors['adviceWrapper']().innerHTML = template({slip: [data.slip]});`